# Primes and 32 - where did this pattern come from?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, sieve-theory

If we position all the natural numbers into a 'periodic table' with the period equal to $32$, we get the following pattern for primes.

The primes are colored according to their last digit. I did not color the primes past the first 'full diagonal', but the pattern continues indefinitely. The numbers on the 'prime diagonals' that are composite are in bold.

> How can this pattern be explained? I'm genuinely surprised by it.

**Edit** The so called 'pattern' was explained to me as trivial in the answers but what about the bold numbers $[49,77,91,119,121,133,143,...]$? Is there something special about this sequence? Some of them are squares of primes, some of them are the product of two primes, but maybe there is something else?

[image: Prime numbers table]

Comment: The diagonals represent congruence classes mod $30$.  In order to contain primes, the smallest residue must be prime to $30$.  Those resides are $\{7,11,13,17,19,\dots\}$.

Comment: If I have understood your question correctly, this has nothing to do with primes. If you colour _all_ the integers according to their last digit, and then display them in columns of 32, you will get the same pattern, only more so. You might like to work out why.

Comment: It's not about their last digits (that's just in base 10 representation anyway). That's about them being on separate diagonales.

Comment: The are on seperate diagonals because the last digits are on separate diagonals.  This pattern is *ONLY* about base 10 representation.  You'd get a stronger pattern if you used 31 or 33.  If you used base 8 and had 26 ($= 32_8$) in the column the result would be *exactly* the same.

Comment: I think what you're seeing is an artefact of the relative density of primes among the integers up to around $500$:  They occur often enough to give an impression of diagonal bands of color (for reasons others have already explained).  I suspect if you colored *all* the primes in your table, and especially if you added more columns on the right, this effect would begin to fade.

Comment: Explain exactly what it is you think you are seeing.  If it's that primes with the same last digits appear in diagonals, that isn't surprising because all numbers with the same last digits appear in diagonals.  If it's something to do with the frequency in which the appear.... well, what *are* you seeing?  I'm not seeing *anything*.

Comment: @fleablood, I'll try - I see that the number of the primes on each diagonal is roughly the same as far as I've been able to build (which is much farther than it is shown in the picture). I saw some kind of order in this distribution of primes

Comment: No, the number of primes in each diagonal decreases slowly (but too slowly to see in a diagram like this). Eventually, most diagonals will contain no primes at all.

Comment: @TonyK, thank you for the comment. I'll probably write a script in Mathematica to see for myself

Comment: I doubt that the density and grouping is out of the ordinary.  On the other hand ulam's spiral is surprising.  Try graphing this with 33 or 26 and seeing what happens.

Comment: Tony "will contain no primes at all"? Or will become rare.  Are you claiming most sets of n = i  mod m with n prime will have a maximum element?  Okay, if that's theory I've never heard, so be it but... is it?

Comment: @fleablood: Look at the table again: each diagonal contains at most $32$ elements.

Comment: @tonyk. Ha! Good point.  Then yes, several, most even, will certainly have no primes eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this is a little misleading.  If you ignore the primes and mark off *every* number by its last digit (but only consider those that end in 1, 3, 7, or 9) you will get the *exact* same pattern.  Except now the lines will be solid without breaks in them.

This isn't a mystery.  Each column we add 32 to each coresponding cell so by going over 1 column and up 2 rows you will always get a digit that has the same last digit and the lines with the same last digits will always form by going over 1 and up 2.  (If we colored *all* digits we'd get a confusing checkerboard like pattern but by restricting to odd values we can see lines.)

Filtering by primes (or any other condition) will put blank spots in the lines but will not change the basic existence of the lines.

Basically the lines exist because $32 \equiv 2 \mod 10$.  If we used 31 the lines would go over one up one.  If we used 30, the lines would be horizontal.  If we used 33 the lines would slant down.  Etc.

NOTHING to do with primes.

====

But what *is* surprising, is Ulam's spiral.  Google it.  (Which has *NOTHING* to do with what you have done--- which is utterly trivial.)

Comment: Thank you - I used Mathematica code to highlight the primes and there is no mistery here.

Answer (score 1):

Primes do follow a basic pattern, but it is still not completely fixed as subsequent Composite numbers increasingly interrupt the pattern P-P---P-P---P-P etc etc.   If you use a grid based on the multiple of Prime numbers (such as $2\times3=6$; or $6\times5=30$; or $30\times7=210$; or $210\times11=2310$ etc etc.) you will see that there is a pattern of Composite numbers and to some extent Prime numbers. This is useful in determining what is NOT a Prime number, rather than finding what is a Prime.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your edit, all these numbers are numbers such that all their prime divisors are greater or equal than $7$ ([A038510](https://oeis.org/A038510)). This is the only apparent property they share, and this property can be easily proven:

Obviously, since you're looking at things modulo 10, and that you want to locate prime numbers, you didn't look at the diagonals ending with $0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8$ as they will not contain any prime. Hence, no number on the diagonals you consider will be a multiple of $2$ or $5$.

As for $3$, it's a bit more subtle. If $N$ is such that $N = 3k$, then the next element $N'$ on the diagonal is such that $N' = N + 30$, so $N'$ is also a multiple of $3$. Hence, all multiples of $3$ will be on the same diagonals. By consequent, on a diagonal with primes (integers not divisible by $3$), there will be no integer divisible by $3$.

Finally, all non-prime integers on the diagonals you considered cannot be divided by $2, 3, 5$, QED.

Answer (score -3):

There's what you talking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: I don't think it's that complicated!

Comment: Um, no, that's not it